# Changing the compilation arguments passed to nvcc by Rust using cc

Tags: cuda, linker, rust, ffi, nvcc

I am using `cc` to link a CUDA kernel written in C to Rust.
Here is my build.rs file:

```
extern crate cc;

fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .cuda(true)
        .flag("-cudart=shared")
        .flag("-gencode")
        .flag("arch=compute_61,code=sm_61")
        .file("kernel/kernel.cu")
        .compile("kernel/kernel.a");
}
```

I have this error :

> running: "nvcc" "-ccbin=c++" "-O0" "-Xcompiler" "-ffunction-sections"
>   "-Xcompiler" "-fdata-sections" "-Xcompiler" "-fPIC" "-G" "-Xcompiler"
>   "-g" "-m64" "-Xcompiler" "-Wall" "-Xcompiler" "-Wextra"
>   "-cudart=shared" "-gencode" "arch=compute_61,code=sm_61" "-o"
>   "/home/ltei/Dev/Workspaces/rust_cudnn/target/debug/build/rust_cudnn-df924982e63c2363/out/kernel/kernel.o"
>   "-c" "kernel/kernel.cu" cargo:warning=In file included from
>   /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0, cargo:warning=                 from
>   :0: cargo:warning=/usr/include/host_config.h:119:2:
>   error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5
>   are not supported! cargo:warning= #error -- unsupported GNU version!
>   gcc versions later than 5 are not supported! cargo:warning=  ^~~~~
>   exit code: 1

I know that it would work if I could change the `-ccbin=c++` in the command into `-ccbin=clang-3.8`, but I have no idea how to do it.

I could also install another version of GCC, but I'd prefer the first solution.

Comment: Is your question how to change the compilation arguments pass to nvcc by rust?

Comment: Yes! I could add arguments using .flag("..."), but I couldn't change the -ccbin argument

Comment: So perhaps you could edit your question title and tags to reflect what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `CXX` environment variable to whatever you want.

```
CXX=this-is-my-cpp-compiler cargo build
```

This will be used as the argument to `ccbin`:

```
"nvcc" "-ccbin=this-is-my-cpp-compiler" "-O0" "-Xcompiler" "-ffunction-sections" "-Xcompiler" "-fdata-sections" "-Xcompiler" "-fPIC" "-G" "-Xcompiler" "-g" "-m64" "-Xcompiler" "-Wall" "-Xcompiler" "-Wextra" "-cudart=shared" "-gencode" "arch=compute_61,code=sm_61" "-o" "/private/tmp/c/target/debug/build/c-67ec4fdcff2f35d1/out/kernel/kernel.o" "-c" "kernel/kernel.cu"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to write out the environment var every time, or putting it in my bash profile?  I'd like to just be able to run "cargo run", not "CXX=/opt/cuda/bin cargo run" every time

Comment: @vcapra1 you'll have to look at the [cc docs](https://docs.rs/cc/) to see if there's a way. Considering that it's an *environment* variable and will likely be different on every platform or machine, hardcoding any value seems unlikely to  be a good idea. You could also try [setting the environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.set_var.html) in your build script and see if that is picked up.